# How do I match two columns of URLs in Excel where the common value found in both URLs is a 6 digit number?

Tags: excel

I have two columns of URLs in Excel.  The URLs have been changed due to a site migration and share a common value, the common value being a 6 digit number.  I have used the vlookup to match exact URLs but I have not determined what to do when I need to match them based on a specific portion of the URL.

For example,

Column A would include URLs like the following:
http://www.example.com/123456_title-of-post/

Column B would include URLs like the following:
http://www.example.com/title-of-post-123456/

The columns have hundreds of rows.  I need the columns to match up so I can line up other data points manually entered in the same worksheet.

Any solutions out there?  It seems I need some sort of formula that can match them up based on an undefined number.  I cannot say "match this URL that includes 123456 to the other".  I would need to say match this number, whatever it may be, to the same number located in a different position in the other URL in the second column.

I hope that was clear.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No they do not.  Every URL includes a 6 digit number that is unique and used to identify the content asset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are able to create intermediate columns then on column C and D you would extract the 6 digit code with the following array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),LEN(A1))),6)),"")}
```

Notice that the curly brackets represent being an array formula and would be inputted pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` and not them being entered manually.

This formula would output the 6 digit code wherever they are present in Column A (in the formulas particular example). Replicating this on column D to extract values from Column B, you are only 1 `VLOOKUP` away from matching your URLs.

There is one final note that the six digit codes might have a leading zero as that would be dropped when converting to `VALUE`. This is not a concern as long as the same treatment is done to the same code on the other column.

Hope this helps. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If your original list is in column A, and your replacement list is in column B,  the following formula (e.g. in C1), will return the URL from column B that has the same 6 digit string as the URL in A1.

So you can enter this formula in C1, and fill down:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$1000,LOOKUP(2,1/FIND(LOOKUP(1E+307,--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),6)),$B$2:$B$1000),ROW(INDIRECT("1:1000"))))
```